# how to use two dropdown on single web page in php

Tags: php

I am doing the project in which I have to use the 2 drop-downs.

In the first drop-down, I am selecting the registered customer. After selecting the customer's name, the other customer information gets fetched from the database and filled into relevant text boxes.

In the second drop-down, I am selecting the item name just like in the first drop-down. 
But after selecting the second drop-down value, the details of customer get refreshed.

I want to retain customer and item information too.

Comment: a lot of post exist on google. this platform is not a free source code provider.

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. The SO community values when you show your own efforts, so you might want to add some code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What you are asking for is a mixture of PHP, HTML, CSS, Javascript, SQL and AJAX. You need some knowledge in all of those areas to accomplish the task. If you are not yet familiar with these terms, you might want to start with some generic tutorials and introductions.  I voted to close the question, but you are highly welcome to post questions about specific parts of the workflow.

Comment: can u please share the code snippets ???

Comment: Hello, Dani .i have done with the task. thank you for your appreciation.

Comment: Thank you @ZsoltSzilagy for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's a sample of what you could do:

```
<!--myhtml.html (HTML File) put this file into your root folder-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="myDropDown">
        <option id="1" value="Item 1">Item 1</option>
        <option id="2" value="Item 2">Item 2</option>
        <option id="3" value="Item 3">Item 3</option>
    </select>
    <div id="myResultSet">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td id="id"></td>
                    <td id="column1"></td>
                    <td id="column2"></td>
                    <td id="column3"></td>
                    <td id="column4"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<!--myjs.js (jQuery Script) put this file into your "js" folder-->
$("#myDropDown").change(function() {
    var queryID = $(this).children("option:selected").attr("id");
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "php/myphp.php", 
        type: "POST", 
        data: {id:queryID}, 
        dataType: "html"
    });
    request.done(function(msg) {
        var columns = eval("("+msg+")");
        $("td#id").html(column.id);
        //You can replace column1, column2, column3, column4 with the names of the columns on your database...
        $("td#column1").html(columns.column1);
        $("td#column2").html(columns.column2);
        $("td#column3").html(columns.column3);
        $("td#column4").html(columns.column4);
    });
});

<!--myphp.php (PHP Script) put this file into your "php" folder-->
<?php
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = $id";
    if($result = mysqli_query($sql)) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $json_row = json_encode($row);
        echo $json_row;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank You @Chigozie Orunta.it really helps me to accomplish the task.thanks for your appreciation.

Comment: @pradnyapathade, ok that's great. Please mark this answer as useful.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ajax posting to fetch data from database instead of reloading the page. On changing 1st drop down, use jquery ajax to fetch data from database and populate it in 2nd dropdown.

So that you can select the values in both dropdowns without page refresh.